# How to copy the hyperlink from with # in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Cell hyperlink = "https://windchill.com/Windchill/app/#ptc1/tcomp/infoPage?ContainerOid=OR%3Awt.pdmlink.PDMLinkProduct%dfasdfasdfasdf&oid=VR%3Awt.doc.WTDocument%"

Vba code:

```
Url = activecell.hyperlinks(1).address
```

Result:

```
Url = "https://windchill.com/Windchill/app/"
```

I need full hyperlink but I am getting result up to before `#`

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Does the object `activecell.hyperlinks(1)` have any more properties on it? Perhaps the bit you can see is the `address`, and the anchor string is in a different property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It splits the address in 2 properties for me and it needs to be rebuilt:

```
Url = activecell.hyperlinks(1).Address & "#" &activecell.hyperlinks(1).SubAddress
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark it as an accepted answer so the question can be closed.